# What is the proper use of "$html .= '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $id ).'" />';?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, formatting

I have the following php variable

```
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

Which I output in a wordpress template as follows:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

However, I now have to output it in the following format:

```
$html .= '<img src="'.image().'" />';
```

(and some more $html lines). How do I implement this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$html .= '<img src="'.$image[0].'" />';
```

(I hope I'm not misunderstanding the question here)

Comment: just a suggestion, change that to `$html .= '<img alt="" src="'.$image[0].'" />';`-- might as well fix a validation error at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand - Since i've tried it a hundred timed without success, I thought I was doing something wrong. However, it seems to work just now. Thanks for the alt headsup.

Comment: @yitwail To be fair, we don't know what version of HTML the OP is using... In HTML 3.0, it wouldn't have been required yet ;)

Comment: HTML 3.0 is before my time. LOL